# RestKit multiple RKObjectManagers object mapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I'm using two RKObjectManagers, one without an RKManagedObjectStore, (which is the shared instance) and one with. When I attempt to set the RKManagedObjectStore like so:

```
[self.storeBackedObjectManager setObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"conversations.sqlite"]];
```

I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore cannot be nil'
```

It seems that RestKit is trying to access the objectstore of the sharedManager (which doesn't use an object store), in `NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord.m`:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext {
NSAssert([RKObjectManager sharedManager], @"[RKObjectManager sharedManager] cannot be nil");
NSAssert([RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore, @"[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore cannot be nil");
return [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore] managedObjectContext];
```

}

Is there any way to pass a reference to my second, store backed RKObjectManager instance? (This mapping works fine if I temporarily set the shared manager to the store backed instance)

Comment: I've since realised that I can in fact use just one RKObjectManager instance that includes a backing store in this case. I'm using just one baseURL here but was under the impression that I could not mix store backed objects and non store backed objects but this seems to work fine. However, the above problem does still occur when attempting to use the two backed/non-backed managers as described. Could this be a RestKit bug?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a shared RKObjectManager for managed (coredata) and unmanaged models. You have to set objectStore property for that RKObjectManager.

I think you can use two RKObjectManagers separately, just create them using `initWithBaseURL`

Comment: Apologies, my question was incorrect - the problem happens when I do exactly this.