# Why is RestKit doubling my base url?

Tags: restkit

I'm having a little trouble with RestKit.

First I tried to use just RKClient:

```
[RKClient clientWithBaseURL:[defaults stringForKey:@"myURL"]];
```

But I was getting errors thrown by `NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord.m` (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278156/restkit-multiple-rkobjectmanagers-object-mapping)). So I ended up creating a RKObjectManager (though I don't plan on using it):

```
RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:[defaults stringForKey:@"orangeqcURL"]];
manager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"OrangeQC.sqlite"];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:manager];
```

But I'm not able to get a basic call to work:

```
[RKClient sharedClient].username = self.login;
[RKClient sharedClient].password = self.password;
[[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/users" delegate:self];
```

It give me a url error with two urls:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x825f2e0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=//mydomain.com/mydomain.com/users, NSErrorFailingURLKey=//mydomain.com/mydomain.com/users, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x8204230 "unsupported URL"}
```

Any idea why it would double it?

When I print out the base url it looks right:

```
NSLog(@"rkclient url: %@",[[RKClient sharedClient] baseURL]);
> rkclient url: mydomain.com/
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: hi Ryan. Have you solved this problem? Im now facing the same..

Comment: Selvin, I was able to solve this. I think it was that I needed "http://" in front of it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan..I had different problem. I was accessing the URL like POST method. But actually the URL was GET type only. So I had to access it like GET URL by passing the parameters inline with the URL.